# Solve error: Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 0 in list input

Tags: fortran, codeblocks

I have recently changed my f90 editor to CodeBlocks for Mac OS X, and when I try to open a file located in the project folder to read the data, the next error message appears on screen when the code is run:

Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 0 in list input

I have introduced the same code I used to write in Windows 7 using the intel compiler for fortran and Visual Studio.

The code itself is:

```
subroutine read_input_data

use input_data

implicit none

integer i,j

open(UNIT=5, FILE='lifting_line_input_data.txt', STATUS='old', FORM='formatted', ACCESS='sequential')

    read(5,*) C
    read(5,*) U
    read(5,*) alpha
    read(5,*) rho
    read(5,*) wake_length
    read(5,*) wake_eps
    read(5,*) n_chord
    read(5,*) n_twist

    if (n_chord .GE. n_twist ) then
        i = n_chord
    else
        i = n_twist
    end if

    allocate(chord_twist(5,i))

    do j = 1, i
        read(5,*) chord_twist(:,j)
    end do

close(5)

end subroutine read_input_data
```

Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

PD. the data file is obtain from an Excel sheet saved as a `.txt` delimited by tabulations

```
! LIFTING-LINE WING             
! Number of panels              
6               
! Free stream speed [m/s]               
50              
! Angle of attack [rad]             
0.15                
! Air density [kg/m^3]              
1.225               
! Wake length [m]               
100             
! Convergence parameter             
0.01                
! Number of data points given for the chord distribution                
2               
! Number of data points given for the twist distribution                
2               
! Y coord [m]   ! X_LE [m]  ! X_TE [m]  ! Y coord [m]   ! Twist [rad]

0   0   2   0   0

10  0   0.5 10  0.052359878
```

PD2. I have change the format of the .txt file to make it equal to the input files I had used in Visual Studio. Now the file is:

```
6   ! Number of panels                              
50  ! Free stream speed [m/s]                               
0.15    ! Angle of attack [rad]                             
1.225   ! Air density [kg/m^3]                              
100 ! Wake length [m]                               
0.01    ! Convergence parameter                             
2   ! Number of data points given for the chord distribution                                
2   ! Number of data points given for the twist distribution                                
0   0   2   0   0   ! Y coord [m]   ! X_LE [m]  ! X_TE [m]  ! Y coord [m]   !Twist [rad]
10  0   0.5 10  0.052359878
```

And now the error given at the terminal is that the file is not found. As I am a beginner in CodeBlocks, I will explain what I have done step by step because I do not find where I am wrong and I am starting to get desperate:

1. New Project -> Fortran application -> I indicate where I want to create the project file.
2. I remove the main.f95 file and I add the .f90 file with the code.
3. I write the code.
4. I save the .txt file in the same folder than all the files of the Project.

When I run the code it appears the error message of file not found.
The code is:

```
!************************************************

subroutine read_input_data

use input_data
implicit none
integer i,j

open(UNIT=10, FILE='lifting_line_wing_input.txt', STATUS='old',     ACCESS='sequential')

    read(10,*) C
    read(10,*) U
    read(10,*) alpha
    read(10,*) rho
    read(10,*) wake_length
    read(10,*) wake_eps
    read(10,*) n_chord
    read(10,*) n_twist

    if (n_chord .GE. n_twist ) then
        i = n_chord
    else
        i = n_twist
    end if

    allocate(chord_twist(5,i))

    do j = 1, i
        read(10,*) chord_twist(:,j)
    end do

close(10)

end subroutine read_input_data

!************************************************
```

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: How does your data file look like? CodeBlocks i not a compile, it is an editor.

Comment: Also, do not use unit number 5, it is normally pre-connected elsewhere. Use some number larger than 10.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answering the question. I have proved with a larger number (15 and 50) and the same error appears. The data file is a .txt file obtained from an excel saving it as a .txt file with tabulations. I'm new at this website and I don't know how to paste the text of the .txt file with a correct format in the comment, so I'm going to edit the question and paste it there.

Comment: Editing the question is the right thing. Don't use comments for important information.

Comment: Is the file in the right directory?  Is the case of the file name right with respect to upper/lowercase?  If you create a file from within your program, does it end up in the directory your file is in?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your old system did something non-standard with exclamation marks on list-directed input.

Try reformatting your input data like

```
6 / number of panels
```

(the slash will terminate the READ).

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help. I have done something similar to what you have said, which in fact is the kind of file I had used in others projects with Visual Studio, but know, as I have explained in PD2, the code does not find the file, do you know why? I have saved it in the same folder than the rest of the project files. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

i don't believe any fortran compiler ever  automagically handled those comments.
If you want to read this file the way it is, one approach is to make each read handle the error, eg,

```
 integer ios
 ios = 1  
 do while(ios.ne.0)
  read(unit,*,iostat=ios)c
 end do
 ios=1
 do while(ios.ne.0)
  read(unit,*,iostat=ios)u
 end do
```

etc..
if its a one-off you could just edit the file and delete all the comments as well.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help, but I have tried it and it does not work. Although I have made the changes I have explained in PD2 and now the error is that the file is not found... do you know why? I have saved the .txt in the same folder as all the project files... thank you very much.